# Is CiviCRM compatible with Postgres and Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, database, evaluating-civicrm, compatiblity

Is there a version of CiviCRM that's compatible with Postgres and Wordpress?

Comment: Are you looking to run Civi-on-Postgres -- or to integrate Civi with (WordPress-on-Postgres). Although Civi puts its own tables in MySQL, it should be agnostic about the WordPress tables (modulo a few small patches/workarounds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

CiviCRM uses MySQL functions extensively, so it can't be run with PostgreSQL.

This has been raised before over on forum.civicrm.org (at least in [2010](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,14103.0.html) and [2007](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,1079.0.html)). Tim Otten's answer in [this forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=31846.0) may also help understand some of the workings currently in the DB layer (and specific to MySQL).

It could (in theory) be done, but it would take significant effort and leadership from the community who wanted to make it happen.

Comment: On reflection I feel confident those mysqlisms *could* be implemented in pg - but you'd have a high maintenance undertaking, and a small group of users to start with.

Comment: It's a relatively new project, but it seems to me that over the long haul it would be of great benefit to the users to have PostgreSQL as an option for CiviCRM, simply because of how much data PostgreSQL can hold.

Comment: I agree - I'm not a big fan of CiviCRM's MySQLism, but it's the status quo. Similar to the [situation on WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases), but with a much larger codebase and smaller pool of organisations to fund the work.

Comment: If DB size limits are your concern, it's likely to be less work for you to contribute towards optimising CiviCRM on MySQL. MySQL can also handle significant data sets.

Comment: I know a developer who's been working toward this as a side-project, although he hasn't published anything. If anyone is looking to collaborate on or fund such a project, email info-at-civicrm.org and I'll put you in touch.